# Check if variable key is present in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary `d = {'q1': 1, 'q2': 2}`

How can I check, in a `for` loop whether a set of keys are present in this dictionary? Something like:

```
for i in range(0, 1):
    if 'q'+i in d:
       print 'Key exists!'
```

How can I replace the `'q'+i` part so that my code is valid? Basically I need to know how can I concatenate a string with an integer to use it as a valid Python expression to search against.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you usually want a list instead of serially named variables: how about `d = {'q': [1,2]}`.

Comment: @thg435 the input comes from a list of generated radio buttons, and this the format of their names

Comment: @AndreiHorak: still, you can convert it to a proper format before processing - this will greatly simplify things for you.

Comment: `set('q{}'.format(i) for i in range(0, 1)) & set(my_dict)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make `i` a string:

```
if 'q'+str(i) in d:
```

In Python, `+` can only put together two things of the same type (e.g. two strings, two integers, etc).  You can't put together `'q'`, which is a string, and `i`, which is an integer generated from `range(0, 1)`.

Actually, this can be done more efficiently like so:

```
if 'q%i' % i in d:
```

Unlike the first solution, this one creates only one string (the other made two and then put them together with `+`).

Comment: `'q%d'%(i,)` is a little more efficient, as it only creates a single string (whereas concatentation requires first creating a string from `i`, then creating the new combined string).

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
if 'q{0}'.format(i) in d:
```

Comment: @btoueg - No, this method works in Python 2.x. too.  He means "new" as in everybody started using that method recently.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it like that:

```
if 'q%d'%i in d:
```

Answer (score 2):

more elegant for me:

```
for key in ['q{}'.format(i) for i in xrange(0, 1)]:
    if key in my_dict:
        print "key exists!"
```